# Is there an easy way to get 15 stack overflow points?

Tags: discussion, gaming-the-system

I need to start up-voting some of the brilliant answers I see on this site. Is there an easy way to get 15 reputation points so I can start doing that ASAP? I don't mind putting in the work to do this, but I just don't know how to "game" the site yet.

Comment: This should be on [meta], if anywhere, but everything you need to know is on [help]. Posting inappropriately is a great way to lose reputation.

Comment: Ask a useful question/Answer some one question.

Comment: I don't think you really mean to 'game' the site.  That has a negative connotation.

Comment: Well, this wasn't the way.

Comment: The best way to game the site is to actually play the game: contribute meaningfully.

Answer (score 6):

Providing one good answer is generally enough to gain the necessary reputation, and more.

Comment: And there you have it; 20 points so far! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You gain reputation when:

```
question is voted up: +5
answer is voted up: +10
answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
bounty awarded to your answer: +full bounty amount
one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
```

If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

You lose reputation when:

```
your question is voted down: −2
your answer is voted down: −2
you vote down an answer: −1
you place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100
```

Comment: Why down voting this answer?

Comment: Neither the question nor the answer is a useful contribution to [so]. I'd guess that's why it's been downvoted.

Comment: It's also a suspiciously fast and detailed response in a very short time for a brand new member...

Comment: It's simply copied from the "what is reputation?" page

Comment: Yeah; @Probably, Pekka ;)